# Digital Signature With TSA Timestamping adding certificates in chain in TSA response PDF Box giving error “not enough space to write signature”

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have created digital signature with timestamping the signature via TSA. In this I have added certificates to build chain in TSA response for building chain  this works fine and signature also created, but while embedding this signature in pdf using PDF box API for Java it gives error not ***enough space to write signature***. Is there any configuration available in PDF box to handle signature size?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have control over the process that signed in the first place? Because if not, then you can't, the space is taken.

Comment: In the signing example, change or add this line `signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(...);`

Comment: did my comment help? If yes then I would make an answer, if no, please tell why. Depending on the feedback I might also add some comments to the example source code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We changed source code as mentioned and it is working. Above setting is required while generating hash and signing hash and embedding signature and creating signed version of the pdf @TilmanHausherr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using an embedded timestamp as in the CreateEmbeddedTimeStamp.java example, so you're using the space of the existing signature. That one is fixed, so you need to make it large enough:

```
signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(...);
```

with a number higher than the default (0x2500). The SignatureOptions object can be passed in the `document.addSignature()` call.